# How to run two node.js apps and mysql in Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have two node.js applications using the same database and running them locally works fine but I would like to run them as Services in docker containers. If I run either of the applications and the database in docker it works fine, but when I try to run both node applications I run into issues.

My `docker-compose.yml` file contains the following

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    build: ./db
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mydb
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_USER: mysql
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
      DATABASE_HOST: db
  admin:
    build: ./admin
    environment:
      DATABASE_HOST: db
      MYSQL_PORT: 3306
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mydb
      MYSQL_USER: mysql
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
  user:
    build: ./user
    environment:
      DATABASE_HOST: db
      MYSQL_PORT: 3306
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mydb
      MYSQL_USER: mysql
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password

    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      - "3001:3001"
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: on-failure
```

And the `dockerfile` for the `admin` service contains this

```
FROM node:8

WORKDIR /usr/src/admin

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

And the `dockerfile` for the `user` service contains this

```
FROM node:8

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

My problem is that it seems that I can only access the last service in the `docker-compose.yml` file in this case the `user` service but not the admin service.

I sometimes says that express is listening on both ports but I can only access the service `user`

I have tried swapping the services and then only the `admin` service is accessable.

What Have I done wrong and how can I fix it so that I can access both services

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the user container you've exposed the ports:

```
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      - "3001:3001"
```

Add a similar section to the other containers if you'd like to also expose their ports:

```
  db:
    ...snip...
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not exposing ports for your admin service, just your user service.

The way your compose currently stands, you're exposing 2 ports to your user service, but your server is only going to be listening to one of those ports.